# Jest render test crashes due to failed fetch post

Tags: reactjs, fetch, jestjs

Here is the code I am trying to test:

```
onDrop(acceptedFiles) {
  const upload = (file) => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: this.props.headers,
      body: file,
    }).then((res) => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        this.setState({ fileName: '' });
      } else {
        res.json()
          .then((result) => {
            this.setState({
              fileName: '',
              total: `Total: ${result.total}`,
              failures: `Failures: ${result.failures}`,
              result: result.output,
            });
          });
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      const result = { body: error, status: 500 };
      this.setState({ fileName: '' });
    });
};

render() {
  let dz = '';
  if (this.state.fileName === '') {
    dz = (
      <Dropzone onDrop={files => this.onDrop(files)}></Dropzone>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {dz}
      <p>{this.state.total}<br />{this.state.failures}<br />{this.state.result}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is the test I have written that passes when I run all the tests but crashes when I run just this test or just the file containing the test.

```
describe('FileUpload', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<FileUpload headers={headers} />, div);
    expect(div).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

The command line shows:

```
C:\Users\path\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\test.js:20
throw err;
^
TypeError: Network request failed
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (C:\Users\path\node_modules\whatwg-fetch\fetch.js:436:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.callback.(anonymous function) (C:\Users\path\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:289:32)
at invokeEventListeners (C:\Users\path\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:219:27)
at invokeInlineListeners (C:\Users\path\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:166:7)
at EventTargetImpl._dispatch (C:\Users\path\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:122:7)
at EventTargetImpl.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\path\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:87:17)
at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\path\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\generated\EventTarget.js:61:35)
at XMLHttpRequest.abort (C:\Users\path\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:405:16)
at Object.abort (C:\Users\path\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:315:13)
at RequestManager.close (C:\Users\path\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\Document-impl.js:146:21)
at Window.close (C:\Users\path\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\Window.js:362:29)
at JSDOMEnvironment.dispose (C:\Users\path\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\build\index.js:44:19)
at Promise.resolve.then (C:\Users\path\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\jest\node_modules\jest-cli\build\runTest.js:102:17)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I understand that the test is crashing because of the fetch (with POST) in the render function but I have other tests with fetch (with GET) in the render function which pass. Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is `url` argument passed in the `fetch` call set?

Comment: I am and passing the url argument, I am typing in the url argument in the fetch, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you review the `upload` function declared in `onDrop` method of the component? Is it invoked somewhere? I really don't see why it should be invoked because Dropzone should only invoke the callback passed to it `onDrop`.  I like that you share the attention to only important aspects of the code. However, it's difficult to reproduce this error without enough context provided.